# `Manifest file is invalid` when uploading my chrome extension to the Chrome Web Store

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I have been developing a chrome extension locally. I just finished it and wanted to upload it to the Chrome Web Store. When I uploaded it and it told me:

```
An error occurred: Invalid manifest. If your manifest includes comments, please remove them as our gallery does not support them yet.
```

I checked the JSON to make sure it it was valid and as far as I can tell it is fully valid. I tried naming it differently and uploading it and it still didn't work. I also tried changing the encoding and that did not work. The Manifest is below

```
{
    "name": "Name",
    "version": "0.0.0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Description",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "icons": { "128": "icon.png"},
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "webNavigation",
        "history",
        "storage"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["js/jquery.min.js", "js/tab.js"]
    }],
    "background": {
        "page": "background.html"
    }
}
```

Does any one have any clue what the problem is? It is really frustrating to get this after finally finishing the extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Used your manifest.json, got this error.

**Could not load extension from '/Users/jjperezaguinaga/samples/ext'. Required value 'version' is missing or invalid. It must be between 1-4 dot-separated integers each between 0 and 65536.**

I removed some 0's from your version and I was able to load it.

Comment: Beautiful!!! Thank you so much! For some reason my chrome didn't give me that error. No idea why not...

Comment: No idea, not even used Canary. Glad to have helped.

Comment: just replace "version": "0.0.0.0.1" with "version": "0.0.0.1"


:)

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
"version": "0.0.0.0.1"
```

with

```
"version": "1.0"
```