# Can't publish my google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i am facing an odd problem when i try to publish my chrome extension via the web store. Every time i upload the zip file i get this error:
An error has occurred: Can not contain the access permissions to the file.

I even tried to upload a zip file that contains only the manifest file but i am still having the same error.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Manifest file :

```
{
"name": "__MSG_plugin_name__",
"version": "0.0.0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "__MSG_plugin_description__",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/ST_19.png",  
    "default_title": "__MSG_plugin_title__",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"icons":{
     "16": "images/ST_16.png",
     "48": "images/ST_48_1.png",
     "128": "images/ST_128.png"
},
"default_locale": "en",
"permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "file:///*","https://*/*", "ftp://*/*"
],
"background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["scripts/jquery.min.js","scripts/utils.js", "scripts/menus.js","scripts/logic.js"]
}
}
```

Comment: Can you try removing one zero from the version number? Some devs have experienced problems when version numbers are over `0.0.0`

Comment: Try using `file://*` instead of `file:///*` and validate your JSON using http://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: @jjperezaguinaga: `"0.0.0.1"` is a valid version because `.(d0t)` separated integers are <= 4

Comment: I [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151058/manifest-file-is-invalid-when-uploading-my-chrome-extension-to-the-chrome-web/14151163#14151163) a question 2 weeks ago where that was the problem, even thought the amount of dots were between 1-4.

Comment: Hi guys, i reduced the dots and changed to file://* but it did not worked but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i isolated the thing: ""file:///*"" was wrong and since i want the extension to run on any opened url, i used "" as a permission.
Change in the manifest file is :

```
"permissions": [
"contextMenus",
"tabs", "<all_urls>"
]
```

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ndongo is correct and Chrome is complaining that it does not have a domain or path (just like the other protocols).

The way you must write your URLs must be `protocol://domain/path` (note you can use * or ?)

So you can replace `"file:///*"` with `"file:///*/*"` or use `"<all_urls>"`